# Is it a mistake or inappropriate if i pass a 2D array and it's size indicator to the same function in C?

Tags: c, arrays, function, parameter-passing

for example :

```
void size(int a, int array[a][a]){
..........
}
```

(I mean is it ok to pass int a and also have varaible a as size of an array im also passing to the same function? I would also like to ask if is it possible to pass 2D array using a double pointer for e.g:
void smthn(int **array){...}?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This declaration

```
void size(int a, int array[a][a]);
```

is equivalent to

```
void size(int a, int ( *array )[a] );
```

where `array` is a pointer to a Variable Length Array with `a` elements.

It is a valid syntax in C99.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( size_t n, int a[n][n] )
{
    printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( *a ) / sizeof( **a ) );
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[3][3];
    int b[10][10];

    f( 3, a );
    f( 10, b );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
3
10
```